# From numpy array to a mhd file in python

Tags: python, data-conversion, simpleitk

I'm trying to convert a numpy array into a mhd file using SimpleITK.

Do you know if this is possible and if so, how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.  Here ya go:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk

img = sitk.GetImageFromArray(np_array)

sitk.WriteImage(img, "your_image.mhd")
```

Comment: It's working, thanks a lot !